# How to use hooks inside non React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm really new to react and I have this

```
import Axios from "axios";
import { useAuth } from "react-oidc-context";

const ProductService = {
    getProductList: () => {
        return Axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "<myurl>",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": useAuth().user?.access_token
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
    getProduct: (productId: string) => {
        return Axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "<myurl>/" + productId,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": useAuth().user?.access_token
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
    addClient: (data: any) => {
        return Axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "<myurl>",
            data: data,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": useAuth().user?.access_token
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}

export default ProductService
```

Notice that I'm trying to use `useAuth()` in the Authorization header and I'm getting `React Hook "useAuth" is called in function "getProductList" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function`.

In this case, what's the workaround so I can use `useAuth()` to get user token.

My Component

```
<Button type="submit"
          onClick={() => {
            ProductService.addClient(data)
              .then(() => {
                toggleModal();
              });
          }}>
          Add
        </Button>
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you have to import react and also your component should be function or class.

Comment: @programandoconro: can I get a code example?

Comment: Show your component. How is this getting called? Call the hook outside of this and pass the value in to this code instead of the other way around. You cannot call a hook from anything other than a React functional component or hook.

Comment: @zero298: please check my updated question with my component. The reason I want to call hook outside is because I don't want to declare `useAuth()` and pass it in every components.

Comment: You could consider making a custom hook, that being a function such as `useProductService()` that returns your above object. In your custom hook / function you'll be able to use `useAuth()`. Then within your components you can use `useProductService()`

Comment: @NickParsons: If you don't mind, can I get a code example?

Comment: Your other question seems really similar, was it for the same issue? [What's the alternative to use hooks inside non React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340727/whats-the-alternative-to-use-hooks-inside-non-react-component)

Answer (score 0):

Hooks is a function that controls state management or life cycle methods of the React component through registered order. So, React Hooks are not available outside the component. Please refer to the [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Only Call Hooks at the Top Level. So, the `getProductList` should be changed as follows.

```js
const getProductList = (access_token) => {
  if (!access_token) throw new Error('No access_token');
  return Axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "<myurl>",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": access_token
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.data;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
};

const YourReactComponent = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getProductList(auth?.user?.access_token)
      .then(() => {
        /* NEXT STEP */
      })
  }, [auth?.user?.access_token]);

  return <>
    Component Text.
  </>
};
```

Comment: the main reason of my question is im trying to avoid to put `useAuth()` and pass it as parameter in every components.

Comment: I don't think it's bad to deliver it as a parameter.
However, if you want to simply use the `getProductList` without parameters, You have to make the `getProductList` a hook like `useProductList`, in the form of calling `useAuth` inside and processing it with `useEffect`.

Answer (score -1):

As per Hooks rule, we can use hooks only from React function components or custom Hooks.

In your scenario,

1. Create one React component.
2. Get value from "useAuth()" in above functional component.
3. Pass above the value to **ProductService.getProductList(auth)** as one of the parameter.

I hope you are calling **ProductService** from particular react component right. Get auth value from there and pass it to **ProductService.getProductList(auth)**

```js
const ProductService = {
    getProductList: (authToken: any) => {
        return Axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "<myurl>",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": authToken
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
    getProduct: (authToken: any, productId: string) => {
        return Axios({
            method: "get",
            url: "<myurl>/" + productId,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": authToken
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
    addClient: (authToken: any, data: any) => {
        return Axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "<myurl>",
            data: data,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": authToken
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}

const TestReactFunctionalComponent = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  
  // use below calling wherever you want inside this component
  ProductService.getProductList(auth.user?.access_token);

  return(
   // your compoent elements
  ) 
};
```

Comment: is there any other workaround beside passing token from every components? the main reason of my question is im trying to avoid to put useAuth() and pass it as parameter in every components.

Comment: If you want use useAuth() in single place, you have to change ProductService  as custom hook and use it wherever you want.