# Use React Hooks in class object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I know it is not possible to use Hooks in Class Components, that is not what I am trying to achieve.

I have a Context I want to access in a service class.

```
/* File MyComponent.tsx */
function MyComponent() {
  MyService.foo();
  return (
    <h1>Anything</h1>
  )
}

/* File MyService.tsx */
class MyService {
 foo() {
   const [dispatch] = React.useContext(MyContext);
   dispatch({type: 'myaction'});
 }
}
export default new MyService()
```

I Have already found a workaround by passing the dispatch callback from the component to the service method. But this is pretty ugly and tedious.

```
function useMyServiceFoo(params) {
  const [dispatch] = React.useContext(MyContext);
  MyService.foo(dispatch, params);
}
```

As this is working I wonder why it is not when I call useContext in the class methods ?
Is there a way I can make it works ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the alternative to use hooks inside non React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340727/whats-the-alternative-to-use-hooks-inside-non-react-component)

Comment: The [ESLint rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#breaking-the-rules-of-hooks) are just warnings that the code is possibly incorrect, though it can't say for sure. While I don't see any good reason to use a hook inside a class method, if that method is called every render, there's no real problems with that. It could be seen as a convoluted implementation of a custom hook.

Comment: why not use [`.contextType`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype)?

Comment: @skyboyer OP seems to be saying the class isn't a component.

Comment: oh, my bad. Misunderstood question.

Comment: Ideally, you should be asking about your situation, so that we can suggest the best solution. Instead, we're presented an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800). Could you provide more information on what you're trying to accomplish and why?