# Using useState variable outside the function in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-state

i have a function, in which i am using a useState hook on a variable named `active`. This variable takes a string value, and on click it takes the value of the category which is clicked on. My goal is to use this value of category outside the function in order to perform operations on that particular category.

Is there a way in which i can export the value which this `active` useState variable has, outside this function anywhere in the project.

the structure of my code is as follows:

```
export const funct = () => {

  // useState variable that will take the value of category that it gets clicked on/
  const [active, setActive] = useState('');


  return (
    <div className='abc'>
      {
        content.map((info) =>

           // Card is the category card which has a string value associated with, i.e. (info.name)

          <Card key={info.name} cardInfo={info} state={active} onClick={() => setActiveState(info.name)} />)

      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

any help would be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the alternative to use hooks inside non React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69340727/whats-the-alternative-to-use-hooks-inside-non-react-component)

Comment: TL;DR: instead of using hooks (and their values) outside React, use outside code inside React.

Comment: That said, nothing is stopping you from doing: `useEffect(() => { someModule.active = active; }, [active])`

Comment: But by the description in your question, it sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800), where you possibly don't really need to use the value outside React, but it's unclear because you're not asking about your situation, you're asking about what you think is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you mean by "outside" the function there are generally 4 solutions.

1. put the state higher in your application scope, and pass the getter/setter into the component.
2. use React Context, wrap all components that need the shared state
3. use a 3rd party library like redux or zustand
4. roll your own "state outside of react" solution. i.e. Just stick a variable in global scope if you're not too concerned with concurrency, or use something like [react-hooks-global-state](https://github.com/dai-shi/react-hooks-global-state) or tips from [this article](https://blog.openreplay.com/steps-to-develop-global-state-for-react-with-hooks-without-context) or similar.